# Is there anyway to set and get data from angular service without setters and getters?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I would like to use a service that is shared among the same instances of a controller, but i don't want to create setters and getters for each attribute, does angular provide anyway to facilitate this? here is an example of what i would like to evade :

```
app.service('YtPlayerService', function(){
    this.playerStatus = {
        status  : 'alert',
        text    : 'Loading The Player'
    };
});

app.controller("YtPlayerController", function($scope,YtPlayerService){
    $scope.playerStatus = function(){
        return YtPlayerService.playerStatus;
    }

    $scope.setPlayerStatus = function(playerStatus){
        YtPlayerService.playerStatus = playerStatus;        
    };
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could generate them programatically to make it more bearable:

```
function generateAccessors( obj, propertyNames ) {
    for( var i = 0, len = propertyNames.length; i < len; ++i ) {
        var propertyName = propertyNames[i],
            camelCased = propertyName.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + propertyName.substr(1);
        obj[ "get" + camelCased ] = (function(propertyName){
            return function() {
                return obj[propertyName];
            };

        })(propertyName);
        obj[ "set" + camelCased ] = (function(propertyName){
            return function( value ) {
                obj[propertyName] = value ;
            };
        })(propertyName);
    }
}
```

Usage in this case would be :

```
app.service('YtPlayerService', function(){
    this.playerStatus = {
        status  : 'alert',
        text    : 'Loading The Player'
    };
    generateAccessors( this, ["playerStatus"] );
});
```

Another example

```
var obj = {};
generateAccessors( obj, ["playerStatus", "name"]);
obj.setName(3);
obj.getName(); //3
```